# Retrieving web view link of a Google shared drive folder

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the webviewlink of  google shared

API: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files

am unable to get webviewlink of particular shared drive folder.

my input will be the folder id:

```
{
   "id": "1Vat7pdwnpg8i2xMzhic4dOVbadZNv0OJ"
}
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: What is the response you are getting now?  What type of file is it?  Not all file types create web links

Comment: Its a folder id, am only getting the child folder details. for eg.  "name": "Google Drive, Notes and Attachments",
      "parents": [
        "1Vat7pdwnpg8i2xMzhic4dOVbadZNv0OJ"
      ],
      "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gvrstU9dumEyY9VzV9io4rS_m-zE6lRZ" But i need webViewLink the folder id which am passing

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the exact request you are making its hard to help but i can say this apears to work fine.  I can get the the record for a google drive directory shared with me and that directory contains a web view link which has the same file id as the one i sent.

## Request

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1nhladm_nRRee6rVER9ZA5QqnyKwfG7l?fields=*&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

## response

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1nhladm_nRRee6rVER9ZA5QqnyKwfG7l",
 "name": "ML GDE Model Deployment Project",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
 "starred": false,
 "trashed": false,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "parents": [
  "1OYYiVmqFp9ZvuRSuVgC_ihkdYirLnu"
 ],
 "spaces": [
  "drive"
 ],
 "version": "461",
 "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nhladm_nRRee6rVER9ZA5QqnyKwfG7li",
 "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/vnd.google-apps.folder+shared",
 "hasThumbnail": false,
 "thumbnailVersion": "0",
 "viewedByMe": false,
 "createdTime": "2020-04-02T04:21:47.275Z",
 "modifiedTime": "2020-11-02T13:58:51.042Z",
 "modifiedByMe": false,
 "owners": [
  {
   .....
  }
 ],
 "lastModifyingUser": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  
 },
 "shared": true,
 "ownedByMe": false,
 "capabilities": {
  "canAddChildren": false,
  "canAddMyDriveParent": false,
  "canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
  "canChangeViewersCanCopyContent": false,
  "canComment": false,
  "canCopy": false,
  "canDelete": false,
  "canDownload": true,
  "canEdit": false,
  "canListChildren": true,
  "canModifyContent": false,
  "canMoveChildrenWithinDrive": false,
  "canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive": false,
  "canMoveItemOutOfDrive": false,
  "canMoveItemWithinDrive": false,
  "canReadRevisions": false,
  "canRemoveChildren": false,
  "canRemoveMyDriveParent": true,
  "canRename": false,
  "canShare": false,
  "canTrash": false,
  "canUntrash": false
 },
 "viewersCanCopyContent": true,
 "copyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
 "writersCanShare": true,
 "folderColorRgb": "#8f8f8f",
 "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
 "isAppAuthorized": false
}
```

The web view link for this request is https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nhladm_nRRee6rVER9ZA5QqnyKwfG7l  which is the same as the file id that i sent it.

File Ids change as do the web view links and its possible that they are out of sync.